# How to specify list of actions for Publisher plugin in post build section in Jenkins?

Tags: configuration, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I'm using Jenkins 1.554.3 and specifying conditional action for Flexible publish as a post build step.

Looking on the list of available actions I can see that it contains only post-build steps.

How I can update this list with the list with the actions available from build steps and specify as action for Flexibly publish post build step?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Use [**Jenkins Any Build Step**](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Any+Build+Step+Plugin) plugin. It allows to use Publishers (post-build actions) as Build Steps and vice-versa.

Then, under Jenkins Global Configuration, there is a **Flexible Publish** section. Set the value to `Any build step`. This will allow build steps under post-build actions.

For the sake of completeness, to allow post-build action under build steps, there is a section **Conditional buildstep**. Set the value there to `Any build step` too.

Comment: Hello Slav, right, I had this installed already but the list of actions wasn't updated. Does it require some configuration?

Comment: Yes, under global Jenkins configuration, there is **Flexible publish** section. Set it to `Any build step`. I will update the answer

Comment: In the latest version of Jenkins the configuration needs to be done on the `Manage Jenkins → Configure System` page